# Drawing a custom component

Tags: codenameone

This is kind of 2 questions:
1) Is the overriding the `paint` member of a `Component` the best approach for a simple 2D graphics game using codename one? Or should I not even be attempting it??
2) Why does the code below draw my `Component` only to erase it instantly?

I initialise my component like this:

```
protected void StartGame()
{
    final Component newC = new PaintedComponent();

    Container mv = findContainerMainVisual();

    mv.addComponent(newC);
    mv.setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);
    mv.animateLayout(200);
}
```

And then the component overrides the `paint` member function like this:

```
public class PaintedComponent extends Component {
    private int nextColour;

    public PaintedComponent() {
        super();
        setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        nextColour = 0x8f8f8f;
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); // I've tried without this, but it's the same
        g.setColor(0xffffff);
        g.fillRadialGradient(0xffffff, nextColour, 0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Poker demo](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/08/codename-one-article-in-sdj.html) in Codename One which you can see in the latest batch of demos, it takes a very different approach although overriding paint should work just fine too.

The reason the component isn't showing is because its sized to 0 when the animateLayout() method validates the screen. You should either place it in the center of a border layout (to take up all available space and disable scrolling) or override calcPreferredSize() to return a sensible size.

I would suggest avoiding radial gradients since they are REALLY slow on some platforms. See [this](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---improve-application-performance-or-track-down-performance-issues.html) about performance.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I've looked at the Poker demo, but I don't think I can get what I want to work by moving components about - cool idea though :)
If I wanted to show an object orbiting around another do you think I could I do that using the "Poker technique"?

Comment: In addition, overriding `calcPreferredSize()` didn't seem to do anything, but `center of border layout` works a treat :)

Comment: Its hard for me to tell from the description but you could create your own layout manager and use that to position components any way you like. Layout managers are actually pretty simple to create, there's a sample of doing that in the developer guide.