# How to use Canvas in Codenameone

Tags: java, cross-platform, android-canvas, codenameone

I want to build an app for different Platforms and I want to used canvas (build a framework on top of the canvas and do such a things like drawing shapes, lines and more) i am using Codenameone java platform for cross platform but i cant add a canvas and draw on it in Codenameone.
how is it possible to do something like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239559/drawing-a-custom-component)

Comment: @MadProgrammerTnx but the code it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just derive component and override `paint(Graphics)` to draw. Place it in the center of a border layout form.

You can also override paint in `Form` but you would run into some issues.

Comment: thank you so much but i don't get it at all. i got a problem i creating an image object and drawing on it but i dont know how to append it to the form how is it possible?

Comment: graphics.drawImage() or addComponent(new Label(image))

Comment: Thank you so much another question how is it possible to add event on this image, events such as tap, long press and more. in general i want use this image as canvas and draw on it with user actions.

Comment: No. Events are on the component where you draw the image. Just override the relevant methods there see the javadoc: https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html